# Static type checking error for groovy collection.addAll

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

This message is also posted on grails mailing list.
In addition to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160761/where-do-all-methods-attributes-get-wired-into-grails-controlller) I downloaded the grails source from github.
 Building via documented gradlew install works (almost) perfect. Than I imported the whole project into Eclipse. And with a bit fighting groovy plugins and "project - workspace-groovy-compiler-issues" I only have a few issues left, all boiling down to java Collection modification in groovy classes. For instance in PluginBuildSettings.groovy:

```
List<Resource> artefactResourcesList = []
  ...
artefactResources.addAll compileScopePluginInfo.artefactResources
```

which gives an error:

Groovy:[Static type checking] - Cannot call java.util.List#addAll(java.util.Collection ) with arguments  [java.util.Set ]

I really don't see what the issue may be.

I tried changing the artefactResources declaration in PluginScopeInfo from:

```
Set<Resource> artefactResources = []
```

to:

```
Set<Object> artefactResources = []
```

which takes away error above, but introduces some other problems let alone the unittests. I'm not hindered with extensive groovy knowledge but it looks all perfect valid to me.

I'm using ggts: 
Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 
Version: 3.1.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201210061306
groovy-compiler: 2.0.4.xx -20120921
On mac os x 8.2
java 6.0._37
groovy compiler: 2.0 (workspace and project).

With my favorite search engine I found a reference to grails bug 5516, which is solved but it looks resurected

```
Type checker fails verification of generic types with addAll
```

Fixed in 2.0 rc 3,